# Is it possible to create a MySQL table within a database other than manually?

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL, I am looking to store user form submissions in a MySQL database.

I have created a database and tested connection to it etc. But need a table to store the data in.

The form has 47 fields, and the only way I can see to create a table is manually via WebMin.

Is there a better way? Thanks and apologies if this has been asked before, I found similar questions, but none that answered mine specifically.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You might wanna dig into the `CREATE TABLE` command.

Comment: Make sure you understand normalization before you design your schema: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Thanks for advice on normalization. I know nothing - so will read that link as best I can :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL to create a table

```
CREATE TABLE MyFormTable
(
   Field1  int,
   Field2  varchar(50), --text with 50 characters
   ...
   ...
   Field47 datetime,
   PRIMARY KEY (Field1)
)
```

[Check this link](http://sql-info.de/mysql/examples/CREATE-TABLE-examples.html) on how to create table or type "MySQL create table" in google

Comment: If he's just creating the one table, it's probably faster to just use a gui tool, rather than writing a script to do it.

Comment: I think it was stated in the question that alternative is needed. GUI is easier and less error.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and replies guys. Would an example of a GUI you are talking about be MySQL workbench? Digging around I've isntalled this, created tables using the UI there. I can tell I am way out of my depth though: I don't really understand all the collation and engine stuff, I also don't havea  good understanding of the variables each column can have. Time to do some learning. I just want a table to store the alphanumeric values entered into a form, so all my columns are:   ``name` VARCHAR(255) NULL` , am I an idiot :) ?

Comment: No, You are not. Look online for sample schemas e.g. CREATE Statements, study the field names and the types assigned to them. From that you can learn what to use next time. For example, Age (int), Text like firstname, lastname could be VARCHAR(n) where n is the maximum number of characters that field can take, mixture of number and text  (alphanumeric) will still be VARCHAR.

Comment: Great thank you, I presume that specifying integers (for example) allows more powerful functionality using SQL down the road. Say if I wanted the product of two fields, it would only accept INT fields as arguments?

Comment: Numbers not only INT. (2.5 X 3.2 is possible) and that's not INT but decimal or float. As I said, determine the best type that reflects what the field represent in real life. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html